# how to convert an object from json format to integer format

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am passing an array from view to the controller using `json.stringify()` method.

That value is passed to the controller and is in

`"\"[{\\\"id\\\":1 "id\\\":2}]\""` format. I think this is in json format, I want to convert this into `{id:1,id:2}` format.

I tried to convert this into string format using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`,
but it is displaying in `"\"\\\"[{\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\":1}]\\\"\""` format.

Can you tell me how can I convert into `{id:1,id:2}` format/integer format?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "{id:1,id:2} format". Do you want a .NET dictionary of integers?

Comment: But {id:1,id:2} is hardly an integer? Do you want a Dictionary<string, int>?

Comment: yes,can u tel me how to get this Dictonary<string,int> format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON data represents an array containing a dictionary as far as I can tell. You could get hold of a Dictionary representation of the data like this:

```
var json = "[{\"id\":1, \"id\": 2}]";
        Dictionary<string, int>[] obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>[]> (json);
var dict = obj[0];
```

I'm not sure if this is what you're after though, since you're saying that you want to display it like `{id: 2}`. If you want to print it out like that, you can build a string representation of the Dictionary:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("{");
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    sb.Append(string.Format("{0}: {1}, ", item.Key, item.Value));
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, 2);
sb.Append("}");
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

This prints `{id: 2}`.

To retrieve the value for 'id', if this is what you mean, you can do this:

```
var val = dict["id"];
```

Comment: Thanks,I am getting the required format,Is it possible to retrieve only "value" value with out retrieving the "key" value from the obj but i dont want to use looping statements

Comment: @steve Do you mean to retrieve the value for "id"? I've edited my answer, take a look at the code at the bottom.

Comment: var dict = obj[0]; if i give this,while debugging,it is throwing Null Reference exception

Comment: @steve Your JSON string is probably not on the correct format, so JsonConvert returns a null reference. Can you supply the value of your original JSON string as it is received by the controller? It is a string object right?

Comment: public ActionResult SearchDetails(string model)
        { var json = model;Dictionary<string, int>[] obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>[]>(json);if (obj != null)
            { var query = (from .....).where(); } } Inside if condition i want store all my id values in a variable with out using looping statement,and in the where clause of my query i use contains method to check my condition,how to get all values inside if condition

Comment: @steve Can you please provide the value for the 'model' parameter as a C# literal? I can't make sense of the value in your question, it doesn't look like parseable JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var data = serializer.Deserialize<object[]>(jsonString);
```

Comment: hi,I have implemented this,I got "[{\"id\":2}]" format,is it possible to display like {id:2}

Comment: you are doing something wrong. Maybe you are stringifying an array of strings. you should stringify array of objects

Comment: I have removed the json.stringify() method and passed like retur{model:val} then with out using javascript serializer the value passing to controller in "[{\"id\":2}]" format.